# Modifying my code to work with delete sql query

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone know how to modify my code to make it work for my delete method? My current code only works for querying and selecting something in a database but not deleting due to the fact that it requires the parameter `[selectNames]` which is the parameter that decides where it will be `*` or `field_name`. E.g: `DB::getInstance()->get('email', 'TABLE', array('user_id', '=', 1));` something like that.

Current code is like this:

```
    public function action($action, $selectName, $table, $where = array()) {
            if(count($where) === 3){
                $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

                $field = $where[0];
                $operator = $where[1];
                $value = $where[2];

                if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
                    $sql = "{$action} {$selectName} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
                    if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                        return $this;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
    }

    public function get($selectName, $table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT', $selectName, $table, $where);
    }

    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }
```

I tried detecting doing and `if/else` by checking on the action whether it be a select or a delete. The reason as to why it doesn't work is unknown if you guys figure anything out about what's wrong in my current code please let me know:

```
public function action($action, $selectName, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where) === 3){
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field = $where[0];
        $operator = $where[1];
        $value = $where[2];

        if($action == 'SELECT'){
           if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
               $sql = "{$action} {$selectName} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

               if(!this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                  return $this;
               }
           }
        } else {
            if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also have tried changing the `$sql` variable if the action is `SELECT` but I don't know why it doesn't work. It does not return any errors whatsoever. I've tried every debugging methods that I know of as a moderate programmer. But I came up empty handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify you `action` method so that it accepts all parameters as an array, e.g.

```
private function action($params) {
    $action = isset($params['action']) && $params['action'] ? $params['action'] : null;
    $selectName = isset($params['selectName']) && $params['selectName'] ? strtolower($params['selectName']) : '';
    $table = isset($params['table']) && $params['table'] ? $params['table'] : '';
    $where = isset($params['where']) && $params['where'] ? $params['where'] : [];
    // Check for params integrity
    if ($selectName == '' || $table == '' || !in_array($action, ['select', 'update',' delete'])) {
        // Handle an exception here
    }
    // Here all your logic for handling WHERE operators and values comes
    switch ($action) {
        case 'select':
        case 'delete':
            // Your logic for selecting and deleting records
            break;
        case 'update':
            // Just in case you'll need it later
            break;
    }
}

public function get($selectName, $table, $where) {
    return $this->action([
        'action' => 'select',
        'selectName' => $selectName,
        'table' => $table,
        'where' => $where
    ];
}

public function delete($table, $where) {
    return $this->action([
        'action' => 'delete',
        'table' => $table,
        'where' => $where
    ];
}
```

Please note that I changed your `action` method to be private.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should call it still in the same way: `DB::getInstance()->get('*', 'users', array('id', '=', 1'))`
The difference is in the `action` method, not in `get` and `delete` methods (I didn't change their arguments). The reason I made `action` method private is that it now accepts parameters in a different way. But as long as it is private, it's not used anywhere in your code, so nothing will break when the way arguments are passed is changed.